# QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running - Calling another PyQt5 file

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am running a PyQt5 app that has a button, that should call another PyQt5 file in a separate window. I set the button to call the 'main2' function in the other PyQt5 that .show the other file. Independently they work great but when I try to connect them this way I get the error above.

```
from ShowRecords import main2

class ExerciseTracker(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.myWindow = QDialog()
        #self.title = 'Exercise Tracker'
        self.myWindow.setWindowTitle('Exercise Tracker')
        self.setGeometry(200, 400, 300, 200)
        self.move(60, 15)
        self.layout = QFormLayout()
        self.layout.addRow(QLabel('<h2>Welcome to the App!</h2>', parent=self.myWindow))
        line_edit1 = QLineEdit()
        self.layout.addRow('Day of the week: ', line_edit1)
        line_edit2 = QLineEdit()
        self.layout.addRow('Body Part: ', line_edit2)
        line_edit3 = QLineEdit()
        self.layout.addRow('Input Exercise: ', line_edit3)
        line_edit4 = QLineEdit()
        self.layout.addRow('Input Sets: ', line_edit4)
        line_edit5 = QLineEdit()
        self.layout.addRow('Input Reps: ', line_edit5)
        btn1 = QPushButton('Submit')
        self.layout.addRow(btn1)
        btn2 = QPushButton('Show Records')
        self.layout.addRow(btn2)
        #btn1.clicked.connect('submit')
        btn2.clicked.connect(main2)
        # layout.addWidget()
        self.myWindow.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.myWindow.show()

def main():
    exercise = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = ExerciseTracker()
    #view.show()
    sys.exit(exercise.exec_())

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

The other file is called ShowRecord what I am calling is this'

```
def main2():
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an event loop is already running with something like this:

```
app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

However there is almost certainly a better way to lay out your gui. One likely way is to create a QWidget subclass that encapsulates the behavior of your Ui_Form and import that class instead of a different main() method. Then you can have your ExerciseTracker widget create children "Ui_Form" widgets, which will guarantee all of the proper Qt memory management, etc is taking place.